# Specifying Body Schema for a Flask Endpoint to be auto generated in OpenAPI Spec

Tags: python, flask, swagger, openapi

I have the following endpoint

```
@app.route("/retry-request", methods=["POST"])
def retry_request() -> DefaultResponse:
  # retry logic that return the DefaultResponse object
```

When I automatically generate the OpenAPI Spec file, it includes the endpoint as below

```
/retry-request:
    post:
      x-google-backend:
        address: http://127.0.0.1:8080
        protocol: h2
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
        deadline: 3600s
      operationId: post_retry_request
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/DefaultResponse'
```

I would like to specify the schema for the body input for the endpoint so that the parameters section with in:body is automatically generated in the OpenAPI spec file, to some how look like below:

```
/retry-request:
    post:
      x-google-backend:
        address: http://127.0.0.1:8080
        protocol: h2
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
        deadline: 3600s
      operationId: post_retry_request
      parameters:
        in: body
        name: body
        schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/input' 
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/DefaultResponse'
```

How can I do so?